# Is there a way to get/make a driver for Intel GMA 3150 that support OpenGL 2.0

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, android, multi-boot, tablet

When released the Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3150 - also found in Intel Atom N4xx, N5xx (Pineview) processors (ex.: in notebook like various Dell Mini or Inspiron Duo 10.1 hybrid Tablet) was described to be able to support OpenGL 2.0; in fact the graphic core is based on the GMA X3100 that is capable of OpenGL 2.0.
But Intel after releasing few drivers updates announced that it will stop support and released drivers only up to OpenGL 1.5 on windows and OpenGL 1.4 on Linux.

The latest driver I can find on Intel site support only OpenGL 1.4.7.

Here is my question: how would I go to update/modify/port/hack the drivers so I do get OpenGL 2.0 support on the Dell Inspiron Duo Model 1090?

Why is this relevant? Well with support for OpenGL 2.0 it is possible to run side by side not only Windows and Linux (as I do now), but also Android OS and its application at full speed using [windroy](http://www.socketeq.com/), and since the Dell 1090 has a multi-touch capable screen it would be the fastest, highest resolution, largest storage capacity and most versatile Windows/Linux/Android multi-OS fully convertible tablet available.

(The reference for the above technical informations were collected and available on Intel site when I was deciding on the purchase of a notebook, I still have some of the downloaded PDF that Intel re/moved from their site, also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_X3100) has info on it.)

Comment: "Is there a way to make a driver" - If the hardware truly is capable then with many hours of reverse engineering and driver development effort anything's possible. Question is, can you do it?

Comment: Not really unless I get at least a primer on writing Drivers for... in this case... Windows 7.